# Javascript client-side what databases are available excluding browser specific ones

Tags: javascript, database, html

Trying to determine what actual non-browser (HTML 5) specific databases that are available for use in JavaScript client-side programing. I do not want to use activeX controls.

Comment: What do you mwan by "database" here?  How about something like [store.js](https://github.com/marcuswestin/store.js) that's a wrapper around browser facilities?

Comment: Having something that provides the functionality of like, say an Oracle database, on the client side seems to be counter-intuitive.  Can you describe the need behind having a database on the client side?

Comment: Database being something similiar to SQLite. The application I am messing with requires a database but will be used offline. I am however trying to avoid browser specific databases if at all possible. (not sure about that one)

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a NoSQL-style db on the client you can check out http://www.forerunnerdb.com. It supports the same query language as MongoDB and has a data-binding module if you want your DOM to reflect changes to your data automatically.

It is also open source, is constantly being updated with new features and the community around it is growing rapidly.

*Disclaimer, I'm the lead developer of the project.*

Answer (score 0):

Initially the W3C created [Web SQL](http://www.w3.org/TR/webdatabase/), but that is no longer active. The current flavour is the [Indexed Database API](http://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/), which is a stand alone specification but requires support for [DOM 3 Events](http://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/#bib-DOM-LEVEL-3-EVENTS), [HTML5](http://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/#bib-HTML5), [WebIDL](http://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/#bib-WEBIDL) and [WebWorkers](http://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/#bib-WEBWORKERS).

Recent browsers should provide some support, however I don't think it's all that complete and certainly not ubiquitous. If you are targetting popular mobile devices or recent desktop browsers, you may be OK.